# How to determine whether or not our webpage had connected to our server

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

currently developing a C# app which shows a webpage from a server. I'm using below to navigate to the webpage:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://10.10.10.123:1000");
```

If the ip is correct the webpage will be shown. I'm thinking of if the ip is wrong, how do we detect and show a error message out?

Currently for me, if the ip is wrong, it just show a white blank page.

Comment: Does it need to be an IP? Can you not give the server a DNS name?

Comment: Read site content, validate IP from a available database/config file?

Comment: @Izzy, I tried try{}.. catch() but nothing come out.

Comment: What about Ping.Send(IPAddress) ?

Comment: @usselite, I saved the ip address in a file, and then when the app runs, it will read the ip address from the file and goes to that page. I just want some failure detection. What if the user saved a wrong ip address into the file?

Comment: @prashant, can explain more about the Ping method? But aren't that every device which is online or connected to the network will reply if we use ping? How do we know which is the correct ping?

Comment: System.Net.IPAddress address = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"); 
PingReply reply = pingSender.Send (address);

    if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
    {
// DO YOUR LOGIC
}. And how can you get the content from the device to which you can not connect?

Comment: There are many ways to check for that address.Using `Ping`, `HttpWebResponse`, `DocumentCOmpleted` event , ... .What is your requirement exactly?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain a bit more if it is for one specific webpage or would the ip address from a google.com for example also be sufficient/acceptable to show you the page? Basically asking, do you want to validate an IP address or are you searching for some specific content which is only available at the given ip?